# ¿Is there a way to don't permanently transform my unity prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that when a camera detects a QR code, a model appears. I use prefabs for these models, a white cube with some decorations over it.

The "raw instantiate" made the object appear way too far away from the qr code (example, the qr is in pos 0,0,0, once the instantiate happened, the object appears at 45,30,27), and also extremely small.

So I wrote the following code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class model_caller : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public GameObject modelo;

    public Transform place;

    private Vector3 scaleChange;

    void Start()
    {

        Instantiate(modelo, place);
        modelo.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        modelo.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is how it looks on the editor:

[Editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECBje.png)

Now, the 2st time I try the code, it works no problem, but once I turn off the play mode, the prefab changes wildly, the scale transform applies to the prefab by itself, thus making it basically unusable.

Why is this happening? Did I forget to write a line of code?

EDIT: I did a build of the app and used it on my phone. There, the prefabs don't change size abnormally, so the problem only happens in the unity editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have it scaled (20,20,20) in the editor and in your code you scale it to (1,1,1), so when playing it is smaller, in the editor it is large, just change the scale in the editor in the top right to (1,1,1)

Comment: That's the plan!